# how to implement "blocking"/wait for rsync?

Tags: bash, rsync

I am using `rsync -acn --out-format=%n /abc/home/sample1/* server2:/abc/home/sample2/` to compare local directory to a remote directory. Then, if local has files not in remote, I will scp the files to remote. This is done inside a while loop.

```
while true
do
    contents=$(rsync -acn --out-format=%n /abc/home/sample1/* server2:/abc/home/sample2/)
    if [ $contents != "" ]; then
        for word in $contents; do
            #scp $word 
        done
    fi
done
```

I would like to implement a functionality similar to inotifywait's -m flag (monitor) that will wait until there is an event. I assume this is similar to a thread blocking until there is some event to process then it will process the event, else it will not busy spin and consume cpu. I tried looking at using watch, but it seems to be more like scheduling the rsync to happen every N seconds instead. Is what I want to achieve possible?